# How to add a value to rows of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, output

Title may be confusing here so I'll explain.

Essentially my code reads a csv file, read through it to see which ones I want and output the ones match my condition to a separate file. The problem is I want to add a column to the row that I'm outputting in the beginning of the row. For example, the row I examine and output would look like this:

```
1, 2, 3
```

I want to add a column in the beginning so it looks like this:

```
yes/no, 1, 2, 3
```

How do I efficiently go about doing this? This is a sample of how I am outputing rows to a csv file:

```
for row in matching_app:
    if line[0] in exceptions:
        csv_e.writerow(line)
        break
```

Comment: How about `csv_e.writerow(['yes/no'] + line)`?

Comment: Is `yes/no` a column or  just a string?

Comment: Perfect time to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module? :)

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Wow that solved it I can't believe it was that simple! Thank you